# Attach SKSpriteNode to another SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a Player SkSpriteNode that needs to pickup an Object. Once the Object is picked up, it should be attached to the player. I don't really care where the object is (to a side, above, center, etc), but it needs to **stick** to the player and not move from it's position.

With the code below I can get it to stick, but once the Player falls from a platform, the Object lags behind it, almost like it's lighter than the Player. I've tried pinning it, but that affects how high my Player jumps. Setting dynamic or gravity to false doesn't seem to help either.

The code below is in the Player Class.

```
func pickedUpObject(object: ObjectClass) {
    object.removeFromParent()
    object.position = CGPoint(x: -20, y: -5)
    object.zPosition = 0

    self.addChild(pollen)
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sensed seems to bear no relationship to the problem you're describing  - you remove the object from its parent (which is what - the scene?) change its position to something based upon x & y (what are these - the player's position?) and then add it to self (is this the player?). Concentrating on the description of your problem - read up on physicsJointPin and pin the object to your player.

Comment: Does player and the object that should be picked have physics bodies ?

Comment: What is `pollen`? How it is related to the `object` begin removed? What is `self`, the player? What about physical bodies of them?